# VS2010 Debugger will not open browser when debugging ASP MVC project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, debugging

I am trying to debug an ASP MVC 3 project in Visual Studio 2010. However, once the code compiles the debugger stops completely, never bringing up the browser. I am able to run ASP.Net projects just fine from this computer, however this project doesn't seem to want to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This turned out to be a result of no start up project being selected. Simply going to Solution > Properties > then selecting a start up project fixed the issue.